# Navigating between the different areas in Xcode with a keyboard

Tags: macos, xcode, accessibility, voiceover

[image: Xcode screenshot highlighting two tabs in the left hand panel (Project Navigator and Issue Navigator), the main code editor, and the scroll bar overview]

I’m looking to use VoiceOver with Xcode.

Using just the keyboard (and with VoiceOver running) how do I switch focus between Xcode's main editing area, the project navigator, the issues navigator, and the scroll bar overview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcuts you are looking for are the following

- The project navigator is: ⌘+1 (Cmd-1)
- The issues navigator is: ⌘+5 (Cmd-5)
- Main Editing area is (once you have selected a file in the
  issues or project navigator):

  - ⌘+J (Cmd-J) and, after release, ↵ (Return) or
  - ⌥+⌘+` (Opt-Cmd-`)
- The Mini Map: ⌃+⌘+⇧+M (Ctrl-Cmd-Shft-M)

Hope that helps.